# Scalacache pass cache instance

Tags: scala, caching

To initialise Scalacache instance in my service

```
import scala cache._    
implicit val scalaCache = ScalaCache(new MyCache())
```

but i am not getting what is new MyCache() so i have to pass a cache instance to construct a Scala Cache.

how to initialise mycache()

how to create a ScalaCache instance

reference : https://index.scala-lang.org/cb372/scalacache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyCache` is some implementation of `Cache` trait. There is one for each of following:

> The following cache implementations are supported, and it's easy to plugin your own implementation:
>
> Google Guava
>
> Memcached
>
> Ehcache
>
> Redis
>
> Caffeine

Specific examples for each are given under https://github.com/cb372/scalacache#cache-implementations.